# why does my submit_tag submit its own value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a jquery-tokeninput search box, but when i click on the rails submit button it submits "lets do this" in the URL. This is only if you actually click the button with the mouse. If you hit enter while the text-input has focus it seems to work fine

```
<%= form_tag(tags_path, :method => :get, :class => "with-bg") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q, nil, :id => "no-custom-tokens") %> 
  <%= submit_tag "let's do this", :class => "button" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ok I deleted my answer, can you specify more clearly by _If you hit enter while the text-input has focus it seems to work fine_ What is working fine supposed to do?

Comment: fine means its not submitting "lets do this" in the url query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct behavior is to submit it's value (in your case "lest do this") on click because that way you can have multiple submit buttons on the same form:

imagine an email client, you have a table with a lot of emails, one checkbox per email and more than one action (delete selected, move selected, archive selected, etc)

if you click you have to know what button you have clicked, i guess it doesn't send the value when you press enter because it uses the first submit button and you can assume that if you have no param from any submit button

i think your form is working fine